# Game Development Resources?

Tags: iphone, software-engineering, objective-c

I want to make an iPhone game and I was wondering if somebody could point me to some resources. Before you rage and close this, I am not looking for just a tutorial on programming, I could just google that.

I need to find a tutorial on how to actually make a game, as in how to organize your code, what type of methods to run in separate threads, how to manage these threads in a game, etc. I already know everything I need; I can write a physics engine from scratch, I can write a 3D graphics pipeline from scratch, and so on. What I cannot figure out is how to combine all of this knowledge into correctly and efficiently making a game. Obviously for this one would probably go to college, but seeing as I am still in high school, that is not an option.

If anyone would know some tutorials or resources, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm closing this because it's way too broad.  And "going to college" isn't really the way to do it.  You get that knowledge by just making games and seeing what works and what doesn't, or by working with people who have done that before, or by using engines that have solve those problems.

Comment: From your questions, it appears that you already know enough to get started. If you know to run background threads, physics engines, graphics piplines then do what @Tetrad suggested and start prototyping.

Comment: "what type of methods to run in separate threads, how to manage these threads in a game" Why do you think that a game should *require* threading? Indeed, anything that would remotely be called a "game making tutorial" should never involve threads; that's way to complex and error-prone for this level of development.

Comment: Also, the most efficient way to make a game is to *make it*, not to quibble about whether it's going to be "efficient."

Comment: I realize that I'm seven years late, but I upvoted this.